# extjs xmlstore: I get an error on JSON decode, but I'set an XML reader

Tags: xml, extjs

I'm trying to load an xml file inside a store, but on loading I have an exception with message "Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON". I don't understand this message because I've set an XML reader.

Here you are my test.xml content:

```
<GetFeatureInfoResponse>
  <Layer>
    <Name>Comuni</Name>
  </Layer>
</GetFeatureInfoResponse>
```

here you are my javascript code to define model and load store:

```
Ext.define('TestComplete.model.DataModelGIFLayer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name', mapping: 'Name'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'test.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'Layer',            
        }
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'TestComplete.model.DataModelGIFLayer',
});

store.load({
    scope: store,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        var count = store.count();
        console.log(records);
    }
});
```

Any idea about what's wrong?...

Best regards

Francesco

Comment: I've taken your sources and tested it and it works as expected: no errors, one record is loaded. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your test and answer, it helped. Yes the problem comes from a different place. At login I make a call of Ext.Ajax.request and I register a callback for requestcomplete. So when I load this store, two callback are triggered, one is what I've written above and the second one is a function for login where I call Ext.JSON.decode (ok at login, no ok on loading store). So now I have to find a way to unregister my login callback after using it. Regards.